# Alzheimer's drug Aduhelm causing viral encephalitis

Tags: human-biology

Over 40% of patients who received Biogen's anti-amyloid beta drug Aduhelm had "brain swelling or bleeding." (See, https://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamainternalmedicine/fullarticle/2792897) Could these reports of swelling/bleeding include viral encephalitis? I haven't been able to find any sources indicating that this is what patients had, but there is reason to believe that removing amyloid beta from the brains of Alzheimer's patients could increase viral encephalitis (see, https://www.cell.com/neuron/pdf/S0896-6273(18)30526-9.pdf). Is there a reason that the clinical trial monitors/sponsors would not have to publicly report it as such?

Comment: Why do you think it is viral encephalitis?

Comment: Hey @Chris, thanks for your message. The second link is to a paper published in Cell - it shows that when herpes simplex virus 1 (HSV1) infects a transgenic Alzheimer's Disease mouse model, the infection leads to increased amyloid beta deposits. These increased amyloid beta deposits (specifically Aβ42 oligomers) protect mouse models from herpesvirus encephalitis and inhibit several types of herpesviruses. This indicates that when Aduhelm clears amyloid plaques from the brain, it could inadvertently let herpesviruses go wild...

Comment: ... Many papers have shown that herpesviruses, including HSV1, HHV-6A, and HHV7 (and others) are consistently found in the brain, specifically in the parts of the brain most ravaged by Alzheimer's Disease (see, Readhead et al., 2018 - https://www.cell.com/neuron/pdf/S0896-6273(18)30421-5.pdf)

Comment: I suggest that SE Medical Sciences would be a better fit for this question. The examples of appropriate questions for this site in the [Tour] do not suggest clinical trials or disease are part of the SE Biology remit.

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I think this site is correct for the question because it falls under "questions about the biological mechanisms behind medical conditions."